# How can I have access to values in the octomap datasets

Tags: ros, octomap, octomap-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to have access to hitting points, colors and pose coordinate values in the octomap datasets (e.g. to use octomap datasets in MATLAB). The datasets I am talking about are available in this [link](http://ais.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/projects/datasets/octomap/) . The dataset are in the form of .ot, .bt and .graph files. It says that .graph files contain raw sensor readings at registered poses in a binary format. You can convert them to .bt and .ot (the final occupancy map format).

How can I have access to the point and color information? I mean to have them (hitting points, colors and pose coordinate) in the from of a text file or something like that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194497/how-can-i-have-access-to-values-in-the-octomap-datasets/) by [AliAs](https://answers.ros.org/users/20060/alias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-10-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The end points and scans with poses are stored in a format proprietary for OctoMap. The OctoMap tool "graph2tree" can read them, so your best starting point would be to have a look at the file [graph2tree](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap/blob/devel/octomap/src/graph2tree.cpp), specifically `ScanGraph::readBinary(...)`.

However, there is no color information stored in them.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2014-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0